# How to use a Linux Amazon Kernel (amzn) repository for Debian

Tags: amazon-ec2, repository

I am using an Amazon EC2 instance with a Debian distribution that has an Amazon Linux Kernel (2.6.35.11-83.9.amzn1.i686). I would like to download and install the kernel headers so I can build a kernel module there.

Is there a repository server for Amazon where I could find all its headers packages?

I prefer to use apt-get to install the headers, but if someone knows an RPM repository, it should be fine. I could use 'rpm' to install them manually.

I haven't find any information or website where to find them.